# Dropbox not supporting symlinks anymore

Tags: dropbox

I'm a software developer and i've been using Dropbox for years now, primary as a backup source.

For this i always create symlinks of the folders i want to sync, so they are always synced even if the folder is outside of Dropbox folder. This always worked very well.

Now Dropbox simply stopped to support symlinks, and worst, from night to day, without any notice.

They created new folder called 'foldername_symlink_backup_copy' for this folders and stopped to sync them.

After contaction support, they told me i need to move all folders i want to sync to Dropbox folder. But this is not always possible, i want to sync a lot of files that are in system folders and simply can't be moved to Dropbox folder.

Is there an alternative to this ?

I can't understand why Dropbox made a change that really make their service a lot worse !

Comment: And your OS is…

Comment: I use MacOS and Windows, Dropbox sync my files on both systems, using selective sync.